# Error creating container odoo15 using docker

Tags: docker, odoo, ubuntu-20.04

I have this line for creating the containers and being able to start odoo15 but it generates the following error, can someone help me please?

Database connection failure: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

sudo docker run -v /home/contenedor/config:/etc/odoo -v /home/contenedor/odoo:/var/lib/odoo/.local/share/Odoo --expose 80 --net odoonet -e VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.com -e VIRTUAL_PORT=8069 --name contenedor --link db:db -t odoo:15.0

I already carried out the network creation process but the error persists, the container is created and at the moment of starting it it lasts a few active seconds and stops on its own

Comment: Do you have a container with the Postgres DB?
I do this more easily with docker compose, why don't you use this approach?

Comment: Maybe you should add more details to the question, such as version information. Does a host `db` even exist?